# Concrete5 Post on different pages and combine that on one page

Tags: block, concrete5, concrete

I'm working on a Concrete site for my traineeship. As I've never worked with Concrete before and I don't understand the code yet, I'd like to ask some help.

The problem is as follows:

We have a few pages:
- Artists
- Concerts
- Articles
- News

All use a right_sidebar layout(A bit adjusted, it now looks like left main, right sidebar, left sidebar, right main, banner. This is repeated with a loop untill every photo/article is displayed)

What I want to do is:
When I post something on for example: Artists, I want it to be added to News automatically. And when I post on Articles or Concerts, it should also be added to the News page.

But I really cannot seem to find a solution for this!

Is this even possible?

Comment: Oskam, sorry but SO is not site for questions like this. Please ask more specific question. For this kind of help look for more resources on internet.

Comment: Arjan, there are a few ways to do that but @miki is right, this is off topic for stackoverflow. Please post your question on our [area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94596/concrete5) page as an example of a question that is on topic for concrete5 but off topic for stack overflow.